# python-mplayer not opening mp3 file

Tags: python, audio, mp3, mplayer

Hi Iam trying to build a small audio player, integrating mplayer into python

I thought python-mplayer could do the job but I cannot get it to work. Any idea?

seems like p.loadfile doesnt work as ps ax shows
/usr/bin/mplayer -slave -idle -really-quiet -msglevel global=4 -input nodefault-bindings -noconfig all

```
import pygame
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import subprocess

from mplayer import *

audiofile = "/home/user/1.mp3"
gfx_rev_normal = pygame.image.load('rev_normal.png')

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 480))

#background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
#background = background.convert()
#background.fill = ((255, 255, 255))

font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 36)
source_text = font.render("Audio Player", 1, (255, 255, 255))
text_width = source_text.get_width()
source_text_x = screen.get_width() / 2
source_text_x = source_text_x - (text_width/2)
source_text_y = 10
screen.blit(source_text,(source_text_x, source_text_y))

Player.exec_path="/usr/bin/mplayer"
p = Player()
p.loadfile('audiofile')
#p.pause()
p.volume=100

running = True
while running:

    time.sleep(0.1)
    print p.stream_pos
    screen.blit(gfx_rev_normal,(30,120))
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        running = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the mplayer API, but maybe it's just this small oversight:

```
p.loadfile('audiofile')
```

which should be

```
p.loadfile(audiofile)
```

as the path of your file is in the variable audiofile, not the string `'audiofile'`.

Comment: oh my god and that took me two hours! Thank YOU!